# Make TSLint follow my rules in JS files

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

I'm using TSLint within Visual Studio Code (via the TSLint extension), and it's great for `.ts` files.  It also runs on `.js` files, which is good, but it does not use the same rules, which is bad (for me).  How can I make it use the same rules?

My `tslint.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": "tslint:latest",
  "rules": {
    "indent": [true, "tabs"],
    // a bunch of others
  }
}
```

And for example, I'm getting this warning in a `.js` file:

```
[tslint] space indentation expected (indent)
```

(It wants me to use space indentation, when my rules are set up for `"tabs"`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify what rules you want to run on JS files via a `jsRules` property in your [`tslint.json` file](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/tslint-json/). For example:

```
{
  "extends": "tslint:latest",
  "rules": {
    "indent": [true, "tabs"],
    // a bunch of others
  },
  "jsRules": {
    "indent": [true, "tabs"],
    // a bunch more rules
  }
}
```

If you're extending `tslint:latest`, [these are the default rules](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/d6e3f29f251a60182890f45145e581c495a53a6b/src/configs/recommended.ts#L139) as of the time of this writing and you'll have disable or overwrite the rules you don't want.

Comment: Ah OK. Thank you. Somehow I missed that it uses completely separate rules for javascript!